# Applying Low-Pass filter to a signal with the Bilinear Method - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filter, fft, frequency, lowpass-filter

I have the following code:

```
Fs = 8000;                    % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;                     % Sample time
N=512;                        % Length of signal
t = (0:N-1)*T;                % Time vector


% Sum of a 1kHz sinusoid and a 2.5kHz sinusoid
x1=4*sin(2*pi*1000*t);
x2=sin(2*pi*2500*t); 
x=x1+x2;

% Frequency spectrum
y=fft(x);
fx = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,N/2+1);
plot(fx,2*abs(y(1:N/2+1)))
```

i want to use the following low-pass filter on this signal:

```
[B A]=lp2lp([1],[1 1], 1.069*10^4)
[b a]=bilinear(B,A,Fs)
z=freqz(b,a,512,Fs);
axis ([0 Fs/2 -20 1])
```

any thought on how do it ?

Comment: @PacificStickler i apologize, didn't open my browser lately , but yea sure , this was very helpful , thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

1. Using `freqz`: you only get the single-sided frequency response of the filter and hence you can only apply the filter on the single-sided spectrum of the signal, `x` to get the single-sided frequency spectrum of the output (filtered) signal `o1`:

   ```
   z = freqz( b, a, N/2+1, Fs);
   o1 = z' .* y(1:N/2+1);
   ```
2. Using `filter`: you can bypass using `freqz` if your sole goal is to apply the filter found earlier:

   ```
   o2 = filter( b, a, x);
   ```

**Optimal use of `freqz`:**

`freqz` returns the the frequency response of the filter given the coefficients of its transfer function as described by [mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html#bt829u7). It is best used without returning a value, in which case, it automatically plots the magnitude and the phase response for the right half of the frequency spectrum upto half of the sampling frequency.

We can verify that the magnitude of the frequency response, plotted by the `freqz` command when called without a return value, is equivalent to the response plotted using the following code:

```
h = freqz(b,a,N/2+1,Fs);
plot( fx, 20*log10( abs(h) ));
```

**Ouptut:**

Moreover, we can see that the effect of the `bilinear` filters obtained using either of the two methods described above on the frequency response `y` of the original signal is precisely equivalent:

```
subplot(2,2,[1 2]); plot( fx, 2*abs( y(1:N/2+1))); ylim([0,2000]);
subplot(2,2,3); plot( fx, 2*abs( o2(1:N/2+1)));
subplot(2,2,4); plot( fx, 2*abs( o1));
```

[image]

P.S: Might be useful to go over [FIR filtering overview](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~barner/courses/eleg212/laboratories/Lab_03.pdf) in Matlab.

Comment: oh ok i see that , sorry about the next question but why are both impulses appearing ? the one with 1k freqency  should be the only one appearing?

Comment: this is because of the nature of your filter. You can see from the frequency response that `freqz` generates that the 2.5k frequencies are dampened by about 7dB only and hence you still see a bit of that impulse at 2.5k. However, low-pass filter has done its job because the ratio of the peaks at 1k to 2.5k has increased from 4 to 8.5. You can further increase the dampening ratio by pulling in the pole of the transfer function. e.g. `[B A]=lp2lp([1],[1 .75], 1.069*10^4)` dampens the magnitude response of 2.5k frequency by 10.5 times relative to that of 1k frequency.